# Remove duplicate items and calculate average values using LINQ

Tags: c#, linq, group-by

For example I have a list of objects (properties: Name and value)

- item1 20;
- item2 30;
- item1 50;

I want the result:

- item1 35 (20+50)/2
- item2 30

How can I do this?

---

Sorry guys, duplicate is based on `item.Name`.

Comment: Could you provide a bit more information? E.g. on what basis do you determine that the first and last items should be averaged. Also, you say you want to filter out duplicates, but the example list doesn't have duplicates.

Comment: Spend a few seconds Googling for "MSDN LINQ Distinct" and "MSDN LINQ Average" please.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault while I agree the OP should spend more time researching, he obviously was unware of the term "distinct" (at least in this context).  Besides, "distinct" is wrong - he wants to be grouping.

Comment: @Jonathon Reinhard But even looking for "Linq remove duplicate items" yeilds dozens of results on SO... Clearly needs more research.

Comment: @Pierre-LucPineault did you read my comment? "I agree the OP should spend more time researching" - I was simply questioning the whole premise of "Distinct"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var results =
  from kvp in source
  group kvp by kvp.Key.ToUpper() into g
  select new
  {
    Key= g.Key,
    Value= g.Average(kvp => kvp.Value)
  }
```

or

```
var results = source.GroupBy(c=>c.Name)
                  .Select(c => new (c.Key, c.Average(d=>d.Value)));
```

Comment: Thanks Robert. this is what I want.

Comment: var results = source.GroupBy(c=>c.Name).Select(c => new (c.Key, c.Average(d=>d.Value)));

Comment: Updated with both query and fluent syntaxes

Answer (score 0):

You could do it using average and group by:

```
public class myObject
{
    public string Name {get;set;}
    public double Value {get;set;}
}

var testData = new List<myObject>() { 
                                    new myObject() { Name = "item1", Value = 20 },
                                    new myObject() { Name = "item2", Value = 30 },
                                    new myObject() { Name = "item1", Value = 50 }
                                    };


var result = from x in testData
             group x by x.Name into grp
             select new myObject() { 
                                    Name=grp.Key,
                                    Value= grp.Average(obj => obj.Value)
                                    };
```

Comment: Thanks squid ;) - from starfish