# LinQ getting distinct fields with average number error

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am having a "Type expected" error which I have no idea why.

My query simply link 3 tables together while trying to get the distinct package and average number of rating.

The outcome should be like this

```
| PackageName | Average Rating |
|    SG       |        4       |
|    USA      |        4       |
```

---

```
        IQueryable<Recommendation> recommendationQuery = db.Recommendations;
        IQueryable<Booking> bookingQuery = db.Bookings;
        IQueryable<Package> packageQuery = db.Packages;

        recommendationQuery =  (from recommendationItem in recommendationQuery
                               join bookingItem in bookingQuery
                               on recommendationItem.BookingId equals bookingItem.BookingId
                               join packageItem in packageQuery
                               on recommendationItem.Booking.PackageId equals packageItem.PackageId
                               select recommendationItem).GroupBy(c => c.Booking.Package.PackageTitle)
                               .Select(c => new ( c.Key, c.Average(d=>d.Rating)));
```

The type expected occurs in the .Select(c => new (.....

May I know if I have query it wrongly?

Because

1) I inner joined all my 3 tables together

2) Assuming I have all the table joined, I tried to group them by PackageName to distinct the name to one name

3) I tried to select the average sum of the rating of the same package.

any idea if there's a better solution for this?

[database class diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f8EZ6.png)

[Solution error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VMo0r.png)

Comment: `new ( c.Key, c.Average(d=>d.Rating))` ?? Is there such a syntax in C# ? Not AFAIK. You need to do `new Recommendation` at least. You're storing the results back in a queryable of recommendations, so you need to make sure you last select statement matches that

Comment: c.Key is c.Booking.Package.PackageTitle, but you only have c.Average.  Shouldn't it be something like c.Booking.Package.Average?

Comment: I'm still having error even after adding new Recommendation, the example that I went by was http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17289534/c-sharp-linq-remove-duplicate-items-and-calculate-average-values

Comment: @jdweng uh I tried doing a Control+Space to show the list of attributes/methods that I could call, apparently the c."Booking" is not in the list...

Comment: I have updated my database class diagram in my main post.

Comment: Okking is not in the list because it is a list object.  You would need something like c.Select(z => z.booking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store results back into a new variable to match your new type:

```
var results = from recommendationItem in recommendationQuery
                join bookingItem in bookingQuery
                on recommendationItem.BookingId equals bookingItem.BookingId
                join packageItem in packageQuery
                on recommendationItem.Booking.PackageId equals packageItem.PackageId
                group recommendationItem
                by recommendationItem.Booking.Package.PackageTitle
                into grp
                select new
                {
                    PackageName = grp.Key,
                    AverageRating = grp.Average(d => d.Rating)
                };
```

Comment: Hello I'm still receiving a weird error, please look at my main thread for the image

Comment: Oh don't bother about the error, you missed out a bracket in the front, i only noticed after I posted the image. sorry.

Comment: @YubinQiu Check the query now, I think it is easier to understand this way.

Comment: Erm I've a question, if you've seen my image, I should be casting back the result as recommendation, however I am unable to cast it back to my front view due to me calling .Recommendation which does not have the average argument. May I know if there's any way to cast the results back to my aspx webpage?

Comment: @YubinQiu You would lose the AverageRating data then. I don't think you want that.